# How to signal an R exception from C code

Tags: c, r

The `stop` function in R can be called with a list object in order to signal an exception of a particular type. For example to signal a `foo` exception, we can do:

```
foo <- list (
  message = "my foo error"
)
class(foo) <- c("foo", "condition")

tryCatch (
  stop(foo), 
  foo = function(e){"never mind foo."}
)
```

Is there an interface for doing this (signaling custom exceptions) from C code? The `Rf_error` only allows for raising generic errors, it does not allow for specifying a exception class.

Comment: C++ has exceptions, C does not.  So if you want exceptions, use C++.

Comment: You could call `stop` from C, rather than `Rf_error`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the suggestions above I wrote this function that does what I need:

```
void signal_exception(const char* message, const char* condition){
  //the condition object
  SEXP vec = PROTECT(allocVector(VECSXP, 1));
  SET_VECTOR_ELT(vec, 0, mkString(message));
  setAttrib(vec, R_NamesSymbol, mkString("message"));

  //the class vector
  SEXP cls = PROTECT(allocVector(STRSXP, 3));
  SET_STRING_ELT(cls, 0, mkChar(condition));
  SET_STRING_ELT(cls, 1, mkChar("error"));
  SET_STRING_ELT(cls, 2, mkChar("condition"));
  setAttrib(vec, R_ClassSymbol, cls);

  //signal the condition by calling base::stop
  SEXP stop_sym  = PROTECT(Rf_install("stop"));
  SEXP call = PROTECT(Rf_lang2(stop_sym, vec));
  UNPROTECT(4);
  Rf_eval(call, R_GlobalEnv);
}
```

It basically generalizes `Rf_error` with a second argument that you can use to specify the class of the error.

I don't think it is very elegant to call `base::stop` from C, only to have it call back to `.Internal(.signalCondition())` but I it looks like there is currently no API for signalling the condition directly from C.

Answer (score 2):

A standard example of how to do it in C++ is [in this Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/intro-to-exceptions/).

Taking just the first part with one minor edit:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double takeLog(double val) {
    try {
        if (val <= 0.0) {           // log() not defined here
            throw std::range_error("Inadmissible value");
        }
        return log(val);
    } catch(std::exception &ex) {   
        forward_exception_to_r(ex);
    } catch(...) { 
        stop("c++ exception (unknown reason)"); 
    }
    return NA_REAL;             // not reached
}
```

works as expected:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/ex.cpp")
R> takeLog(-1)
Error: Inadmissible value
R>
```

The remainder of that post has some details.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the answer should be in the source code of `forward_exception_to_r` then.

Comment: Not much magic there, it basically just calls `stop()` for, see eg here https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/exceptions.h#L305:L310